# turn off (synchronized) database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I just found a database, and I have no Idea what to do. I can't drop, update, or anything.

The database is in this state:
[image]

How can i turn it off? Because, it's already off !

[image]

I tried to `restore database ...set online`.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE <<DB NAME>> SET PARTNER OFF` This will remove mirroring.

Comment: i've tried it @kin...`set witness...`, and other commands from books onlinie, nothing is working. it says it's not configured for database mirroring.

Comment: What do you get when you run `SELECT mirroring_role
    FROM sys.database_mirroring
    WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = N'your_database_name'` ? Is alwaysON configured ?

Comment: @kin, it's `NULL`.

Comment: Can you post the error when you try to drop the database ? That will give some clue.

Comment: > BACKUP > `This BACKUP or RESTORE command is not supported on a database mirror or secondary replica.`...> DROP > `The database 'SPTC' is currently joined to an availability group.  Before you can drop the database, you need to remove it from the availability group.
` jesus !! avaliability group...didn't notice that. Now I will try to know how to remove it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is useful to know that the database you are trying to remove is **not** in mirroring. It is part of Availablity group.

You can use below command to remove the database from Availablity group :

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP YourAG REMOVE DATABASE DBthatYouWantToRemove;
```